# Jenkins - Credentials - are they not used when checking items out of a private github repo?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh, credentials

I was under the impression that to check items out of a private github repo you would need to set up Credentials in Jenkins.

However, when I deleted Credentials, Jenkins was still able to check code out of the private github repo.

So, I assume it's using `ssh` keys. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the url to you git repository. If it starts with ssh, it will try to use `ssh`. If https/http it will be normal http clone.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Git Plugin uses the command line `git` client, which will attempt to use any local SSH keys as normal, if you haven't specified any other credentials in the job config.

But as you say, it's preferred to use the Credentials plugin, as then you don't have to manually ensure that the correct SSH private key is installed on each of the machines that Jenkins might run a build on.